# Is there a way to make a cassette bundle URL never expire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, cassette

I am using cassette for bundling and minification. However, given that the URL for the bundle is unique with the hash of the bundle contents in the URL, is it possible set the content expiry to never?

I cant see how the contents of a URL returned by cassette can ever change because of the hash in the path, so it makes sense to stop the browser from requesting the same URL more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Cassette's [website](http://getcassette.net/), if Cassette is running with debug=false, it will send headers that will tell the client to cache indefinitely.